# What's type deduced by auto in lambda expression used to modify a vector of type bool (special container)

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, generic-lambda

I want to change the state of one variable in `std::vector<bool>` using a function by reference but this doesn't work because `std::vector<bool>` is a proxy object. However when I try to change it using `lambda expression` I could modify it. Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    vector<bool> v(10, true);

    auto modify_bool = [](auto b){ b = false; };

    modify_bool(v[1]);

    for(bool b:v)
        cout << b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I can see that `v[1]` has been changed to `false`. My question is what is the type deduced by `auto` of `modify_bool` and `b`?

Comment: `std::vector<bool>::operator[]` returns `std::vector<bool>::reference`. That's what `auto` deduces.

Comment: You could have read the library documentation or used `typeinfo` to answer this.

Comment: Note that `modify_bool` is not guaranty to modify `v[1]`as the packing optimization and proxy is optional.

Comment: @DeiDei Like if I want to write my code without auto, how I could write it?

Comment: @Ja_cpp Easiest way is `[](decltype(v[0]) b){ b = false; };` which is essentially same as auto in this case, or you like, use the full qualified name `std::vector<bool>::reference b`

Comment: ...and this is why giving this thing the name `vector<bool>` was an abomination that might hang over the Standard forever, if no one admits that the Standard needs to come out and specify that this *cannot* be done - and that anyone wanting the *possible* optimisation should use an `std::bitset` or a newly named class that takes over what `vector<bool>` is currently (maybe) (whether you know it or not) doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `std::vector<T>::operator[]` on a non-const `vector` object returns a 
`std::vector<T>::reference`, which in most cases is `T&`.

However, in the case of `std::vector<bool>`, its internal storage *may* be optimized to store multiple `bool`s as bits in a single byte, instead of using a normal `bool[]` array, in which case `reference` cannot be a normal `bool&`. It is instead a proxy object that has `operator=` and `operator bool()` implemented to assign/read a specific `bool` element in the `vector`'s internal representation.

**The type of that proxy is unspecified and implementation-specific**, but `auto` can still deduce it.